# NodeJS dependency : Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, node-modules

I'm working on a NextJS project and one of the dependencies `force-graph` depends on `bezier`. `bezier` is using `type: module` because of which a `require` import fails in `force-graph`. I don't have `type:module` for my project root. Does this mean I have to fix imports of all my `node_modules?`